# How can I use a specific record's value that's the many in a 1:many in a query of the parent?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Here's the classes:

```
public class Event 
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public List<Occurrence>? Occurrences { get; set; }
}

public class Occurrence
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    public Event Parent { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; private set; }

    public int RecurrenceIndex { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to have in my Where() clause is something like:

```
dbContext.Events
    .Where(e => e.Occurrences[o => o.RecurrenceIndex == index])
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

where I pass in `index` to this query. Obviously `[o => o.RecurrenceIndex == index]` isn't valid. But is there a way to do this?

I can get the Occurrence by doing (writing now so syntax may be wrong):

```
dbContext.Occurrences
    .Where(o => o.RecurrenceIndex == index)
    .Where(o => o.ParentId == parentId)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But I'm curious if I can get the parent Event object in a single query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var event = dbContext.Events
    .Where(e => e.Occurrences.Any(o => o.RecurrenceIndex == index))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

... sounds like it is what you are looking for to get any event that contains a reference to a matching occurrence.
If you want the Occurrences then eager load those to ensure they are available:

```
var event = dbContext.Events
    .Include(e => e.Occurrences)
    .Where(e => e.Occurrences.Any(o => o.RecurrenceIndex == index))
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you. It felt like there was a way but I couldn't think of it. And I must admit, I generally don't think of `Any()` or `All()` and yet they tend to be very useful a lot of the time. As always, thank you.